# Device enrollment returns 500 error in OS X Server

Tags: ios, macos, server.app, mobile-device-management

I'm currently working with OS X Server (Yosemite) to try and create profiles for certain devices.  It appears that I have configured the server correctly, and I have assigned a domain to it.  When I try to enroll an iOS device and click "Enroll", I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  Same thing happens on the Mac.

Is this a common issue, or is there something I forgot to configure?

Answer (score 1):

Completely reset OS X Server and all my certificates.  Apparently there was an issue with my self-signed certificate, so enrollment is working now.

Comment: Same issue here.
How did you manage to completely reset server and certificates?
Please describe it explicitly to me.
Thanks a lot!
Andreas